# Проблема с TinyMCE во всплывающем диалоговом окне bootstrap3

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, tinymce

Для редактирования текстов на своем сайте использую всплывающее диалоговое окно Bootstrap3. Все работает нормально, можно редактировать текст. Но при подключении TinyMCE содержимое textarea пропадает и невозможно редактировать. 
Вот html-код модального окна:

```
<!-- Modal --> 
<div class="modal fade" id="add_new" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- labelledby="Labelnew_new" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
<h4 class="modal-title" id="Labelnew_new">Add article</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<form role="form" id="f_new">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="ntitle">Title :</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="ntitle" id="title" placeholder="Title of article"   data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" autocomlete="off"/>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="ntext">Text :</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="9" name="ntext" id="ntext" placeholder="Text of article"></textarea>
 <input type="hidden" name="id_new">
 </div>
 </form>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-footer" id="modal_footer">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="save_new">Save</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="f_del">Delete</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Js-код для активации модального окна

```
function set_new(){
$('#new_new').on('click',function(){ jQuery('form')[0].reset();
$('input[name="id_new"]').val('');
});
$('#table-new tbody').on('click','tr', function( event ){   
var tr = $( this );
var id = $( this ).attr('id');
$('input[name="id_new"]').val(id);
$("input[name='ntitle']").val( tr.find('td:eq(1)').text());
$("textarea[name='ntext']").val(tr.find('td:eq(2)').html()); 
$("#add_new").modal('show'); 
});
}
```

И инициализация TinyMCE:

```
<script src="/admin/template/news/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js">   </script>
<script>tinymce.init({ 
selector: '#ntext'
});
</script>
```

Где я ошибаюсь, как правильно подключить текстовый редактор?

Comment: перенесите код в https://jsfiddle.net/ так быстрее смогут вам помочь

Comment: Добавил на jsfiddle.net  - я там первый раз, прошу строго не судить, вот ссылка https://jsfiddle.net/ZaurK/eaqjnmvd/  . Видно, что область ввода текста в Tinymce пустая - в этом проблема, даже placeholder не отображается. Должен выводиться текст из базы mysql; Если отключить Tinymce , то placeholder отображается, да и текст из базы тоже(правда тут этого не видно).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать так:

```
<script src="/admin/template/news/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js">   </script>
<script>tinymce.init({ 
selector: 'textarea#ntext'
});
</script>
```